# Rails RGeo::Geos.supported? False Can't get rgeo-shapefile working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, shapefile, rgeo

Trying to make [this example](https://github.com/rgeo/rgeo-shapefile) of uploading a shapefile work with my rails setup and, running from the console, i get returned with:

RGeo::Error::RGeoError: GEOS is not available, but is required for correct interpretation of polygons in shapefiles.

also

RGeo::Geos.supported? returns **False**

I'm running -
ruby version 2.0.0p576
and rails version 4.2.0

The gems included are:
gem 'activerecord-postgis-adapter', '3.0.0.beta2'
gem 'rgeo-shapefile'
gem 'dbf'

What am I doing wrong, where can I look to find out why GEOS isn't being found? Thanks!

Comment: Have you installed GEOS? If so, what method did you use (Macports, Homebrew, source install) and what location did you install it to?

Comment: I used "brew install geos" - it ended up at: /usr/local/Cellar/geos/3.4.2
Thanks

Comment: additional weirdness - it does work in irb, but not in rails c. 
% irb
> require 'rgeo'
 => true
> RGeo::Geos.supported?
=> true
BUT
rails c
> require 'rgeo'
 => false 
> RGeo::Geos.supported?
 => false

Comment: Ok - it seems that the explicit inclusion of gem 'dbf' in the gemfile was breaking thinks. commented it out, rebundled, and we're up and running again...

Comment: @user1051849 I have the exact same issue as you. Not supported in the `rails console` but supported in `irb`. I do not have the `dbf` gem explicitly included. Can you think of anything else you may have done to fix the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok - it seems that the explicit inclusion of gem 'dbf' in the gemfile was breaking thinks. commented it out, rebundled, and we're up and running again...

Comment: **dbf** gem is important to read attribute data of records in shapefile.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install RGEO Rails gem

```
gem install rgeo
```

Answer (score 0):

> cd /tmp
>
> wget http://download.osgeo.org/geos/geos-3.4.2.tar.bz2
>
> bunzip2 geos-3.4.2.tar.bz2
>
> tar xvf geos-3.4.2.tar
>
> cd geos-3.4.2
>
> ./configure && make && sudo make install